How to make an application for communication between opc ua client and API?
I want to make an application which serves as an opc ua server (connecting to opc ua browser client) and communicates with an API (http/xml). So I want to make an application that makes the communication between opc ua and an API (http/xml) possible.
i haven't tried anything yet, because I want to work from a starting point.

The overall implementation depends heavily on the API and the type of data it provides.
Start by creating an OPC UA server and adding a reasonable namespace of objects/variables/methods.
There are two options depending on the API.

Poll the API periodically for new data and set the values of the
variables in your OPC UA server.
Register callbacks in the OPC UA
server that will be called when an OPC UA client requests/writes a value.
value. In these callbacks you make the API calls.

If you are using OPC UA methods, implement them like the second option.
